# Grouping results when nesting queries

Tags: t-sql, grouping, subquery

I am trying to get a 6 month trend of entities in my database that match some criteria, however the issue is that I need to nest a few levels deep to determine if an entity qualifies.

The entities are "members" who may have multiple "accounts" and I need to make sure that none of their accounts have certain flags set before I include them.

If I wanted to just get a count as of a specific date (we keep historical data), I would do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(sup.SSN) 
FROM MemberSuppTable as sup 
WHERE  (
  sup.ProcessDate = @PROCESSDATE
  AND sup.MemberSuppID IN (
    SELECT summ.MemberSuppID 
    FROM MemberSummaryTable as summ
    WHERE  (
      summ.ProcessDate = @PROCESSDATE
      AND summ.AccountNumber IN (
        SELECT acct.AccountNumber 
        FROM AccountTable as acct
        WHERE ( 
          acct.ProcessDate = @PROCESSDATE
          --other criteria for account exclusion go here. 
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

`MemberSuppTable` has high level info on members:

```
(ID, FirstAccountOpenDate, status, etc)
```

`MemberSummaryTable` ties accounts to members in the `MemberSuppTable`:

```
(AccountNumber, MemberSuppID, ...)
```

---

Now, I'm trying to get a count for month end process dates, grouped by process date in a single query.

So, where the above query would return

```
ssn count
----------
1,000,000
```

I want:

```
process date | ssn count
------------------------
20160430     | 8,000,000
20160551     | 8,500,000
...          | ...
20160331     | 1,000,000
```

---

so far I've come up with the following (see below for why it doesn't work):

```
WITH valid_dates AS (
  SELECT D.ProcessDate 
  FROM arcu.vwARCUProcessDates AS D 
  WHERE d.FullDate = D.MonthEndDate 
    AND d.ProcessDate >= @SDATE
)


SELECT sup.ProcessDate, COUNT(DISTINCT sup.SSN) 
FROM MemberSuppTable as sup 
WHERE (
  AND sup.ProcessDate IN (SELECT * FROM valid_dates)    
  AND sup.MemberSuppID IN (
    SELECT summ.MemberSuppID
    FROM MemberSummaryTable as summ
    WHERE  (
      summ.ProcessDate IN (SELECT * FROM valid_dates)
      AND summ.AccountNumber IN (
        SELECT acct.AccountNumber 
        FROM AccountTable as acct
        WHERE ( 
          acct.ProcessDate IN (SELECT * FROM valid_dates)
          ...
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
GROUP BY (sup.ProcessDate)
```

With the above query though, I believe that a member would be included in ALL groups if they matched the criteria for ANY process date in the valid_dates table.

Can anyone help me out? (I'm new to SQL, so forgive me if I'm missing something simple.)

Comment: Include Sample data and Desire result. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The desired result is in the middle of the question... do you mean that you want exact tables?

Comment: Seems like you are using to many `IN()` statements, changed them to joins it will be easier to read and understand and will probably be more efficient .

Comment: Yes, exact tables or a Minimal Complete sample we can use to validate the query. You can use www.sqlFiddle.com to prepare it. Use `Text to DDL` to create the db schema

Comment: Not MySQL, eh? MySQL doesn't have CTEs (`WITH` clauses).

Comment: Are you sure your first query gives the correct result? You say "I need to make sure that none of their accounts have certain flags set", but you only have `IN` clauses. As you want to exclude records where certain flags are set, I would rather expect `NOT IN` (or `NOT EXISTS` clauses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i would rewrite your first query using `INNER JOIN` instead of `WHERE .. IN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sup.SSN) 
FROM MemberSuppTable as sup 
INNER JOIN MemberSummaryTable AS summ
    ON summ.MemberSuppID = sup.MemberSuppID
INNER JOIN AccountTable AS acct
    ON acct.AccountNumber = summ.AccountNumber
WHERE sup.ProcessDate  = @PROCESSDATE
  AND summ.ProcessDate = @PROCESSDATE
  AND acct.ProcessDate = @PROCESSDATE
  -- other criteria for account exclusion go here.
```

This looks more compact and is (IMHO) more readable.

Now I would change the query the way, that `@PROCESSDATE` occures only once

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sup.SSN) 
FROM MemberSuppTable as sup 
INNER JOIN MemberSummaryTable AS summ
    ON summ.MemberSuppID = sup.MemberSuppID
INNER JOIN AccountTable AS acct
    ON acct.AccountNumber = summ.AccountNumber
WHERE sup.ProcessDate  = @PROCESSDATE
  AND summ.ProcessDate = sup.ProcessDate
  AND acct.ProcessDate = sup.ProcessDate
  -- other criteria for account exclusion go here.
```

You can keep the conditions in the `WHERE` clause, but i more like them to be in the `ON` clause

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sup.SSN)
FROM MemberSuppTable AS sup
INNER JOIN MemberSummaryTable AS summ 
    ON  summ.MemberSuppID = sup.MemberSuppID
    AND summ.ProcessDate  = sup.ProcessDate
INNER JOIN AccountTable AS acct
    ON  acct.AccountNumber = summ.AccountNumber
    AND acct.ProcessDate = sup.ProcessDate
WHERE sup.ProcessDate = @PROCESSDATE
  -- other criteria for account exclusion go here.
```

Now it's easy to get the `COUNT` for each ProcessDate

```
SELECT sup.ProcessDate, COUNT(DISTINCT sup.SSN)
FROM MemberSuppTable as sup 
INNER JOIN MemberSummaryTable AS summ
    ON  summ.MemberSuppID = sup.MemberSuppID
    AND summ.ProcessDate  = sup.ProcessDate
INNER JOIN AccountTable AS acct
    ON  acct.AccountNumber = summ.AccountNumber
    AND acct.ProcessDate   = sup.ProcessDate
-- WHERE criteria for account exclusion go here. 
GROUP BY sup.ProcessDate
```

To also filter by "valid_dates" it would be just an additional `JOIN` and some `WHERE` conditions

```
SELECT sup.ProcessDate, COUNT(DISTINCT sup.SSN)
FROM MemberSuppTable as sup 
INNER JOIN MemberSummaryTable AS summ
    ON  summ.MemberSuppID = sup.MemberSuppID
    AND summ.ProcessDate  = sup.ProcessDate
INNER JOIN AccountTable AS acct
    ON  acct.AccountNumber = summ.AccountNumber
    AND acct.ProcessDate   = sup.ProcessDate
INNER JOIN arcu.vwARCUProcessDates AS d
    ON d.ProcessDate = sup.ProcessDate
WHERE d.FullDate = d.MonthEndDate 
  AND d.ProcessDate >= @SDATE
  -- AND criteria for account exclusion go here.
GROUP BY sup.ProcessDate
```

For better performance it might be better to `GROUP BY d.ProcessDate`, but don't forget to also ajust the `SELECT` part.

**Edit:**
As noted in the comments, `DISTINCT` keyword has to be used, if every SSN hast to be counted once. So i edited the solution.

It also has to be noted, that even with `DISTINCT` the first query is not allways equivalent to the original one. If `sup.SSN` is not unique, the queries could return different results.

Comment: This causes more results than i want to be returned because there is a many-one relationship between the member summary table and the membersupp table. The inner join between the two creates a separate row for each account a member has, I only want one.  ( can do count(DISTINCT ssn) instead, but I'm wondering if there's another way)

Comment: If `DISTINCT` is for some reason not an option for you - have a look at my comment on Thorsten Kettners answer.

Comment: As the OP wants to count distinct SSNs per date, you must use `COUNT(DISTINCT sup.SSN)`. If it were not distinct SSNs the OP wanted to count, then this query wouldn't even work, because with possibly many MemberSummaryTable and AccountTable entries per MemberSuppTable record you'd get your counts multiplied. This is why one should always use `IN` or `EXISTS` when checking for mere existence. The query suggested as is, is not only wrong but also less readable, because it gives the impression to count SSNs which it does not.

Answer (score 1):

IN clauses are perfectly fine for such a query. More readable than joins, as you show clearly which table you select data from and which tables are only accessed to check record existence. This is well structured and shows you have given the query some thought.

Your query would get even more readable, however, without the unneccessary alias names and parentheses.

Anyway, you want to use the *same* process date that you find in the subqueries, I guess, so enhance your IN clauses accordingly:

```
select processdate, count(distinct ssn) 
from membersupptable 
where (processdate, membersuppid) in 
(
  select processdate, membersuppid
  from membersummarytable
  where (processdate, accountnumber) in
  (
    select processdate, accountnumber 
    from accounttable
    where processdate in 
    (
      select processdate 
      from vwarcuprocessdates
      where fulldate = monthenddate 
      and processdate >= @sdate
    )
  )
)
group by processdate;
```

Comment: I realized that I had accidentally tagged this as mysql, but i'm really using tsql.   It's yelling at me when I try to do a multi-column WHERE IN.

Comment: @LukeP, if "multi-column WHERE IN" doesn't work, you could try to use a derived subquery like `where membersuppid in (
  select  membersuppid
  from membersummarytable
  where processdate = sup.processdate
  and ...
)`. But you will need to alias you tables or use their full names.

Comment: @LukeP: You should use correlated subqueries then, as Paul suggests, but then use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`. This is more readable as we expect `EXISTS` clauses to be correlated with the outer query and `IN` clauses not to be correlated. A pity that SQL Server doesn't support tuples with `IN`.